# Do neutrons that undergo diffraction lose or gain energy? And how much and in what form?

Tags: diffraction, neutrons

Neutrons that undergo diffraction change direction ... is there a change in the kinetic energy of that neutron?  If so, how is that manifested?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question.

Comment: No it is not ... reading de Broglie's PhD thesis ... this issue is not covered, so I am wondering ... if a particle like a neutron is caused to change direction due to diffraction, does it lose any energy?

Comment: Neutrons were discovered only after de Broglie's thesis, so of course it is not covered. Ah well then: ordinary neutron diffraction is elastic diffraction, just like x-rays, no change in energy, the crystal takes the momentum. There is also inelastic neutron diffraction. As to how this is "manifested" - still sounds like homework...

Comment: No, really not homework ... but diffraction has been observed with particles even larger than neutrons ... does the diffraction actually change the direction of the particle?  If so, the how do you account for the energy that would take?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a review of the [neutron diffraction method.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/materials-science/neutron-diffraction)

> Neutron diffraction is a crystallographic method mainly used to study the atomic and/or magnetic structure of a material. The method is an elastic scattering in which the neutrons exiting the experiment have *approximately the same energy as the incident neutrons.* This technique is comparable to X-ray diffraction, although it provides complementary information because of the different type of radiation

Note the italicized word *approximate* as far as energy goes.

The scattering is elastic, i.e. no energy loss, *in the center of mass when talking of neutron-atom scattering*. If one transforms to the lab, elastic scattering has different input output energies due to the transformation .

Diffraction of neutrons is a collective scattering phenomenon, the single neutron scatters with the whole a crystal. The difference in masses, crystal-neutron are such ( avogadro's number is $10^{23}$ so even for dust crystals the lab and the center of mass practically coincide) that the lab system is effectively  the same as the center of mass neutron-crystal. Thus there is very little energy loss in the measurement of the scattered neutron, and the *approximate* is a correct term.